# Define target for CoreAnimation in HTML

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

I am writing a Dart application and using the CoreAnimation to animate some of my elements. 
One of my animations looks like this:

```
   <core-animation id="animOnLoginSuccessForm" duration="500" fill="forwards" easing="ease-out">
      <core-animation-keyframe>
        <core-animation-prop name="opacity" value="1.0"></core-animation-prop>
        <core-animation-prop name="transform" value="translateY(0%)"></core-animation-prop>
      </core-animation-keyframe>
      <core-animation-keyframe>
        <core-animation-prop name="opacity" value="0.0"></core-animation-prop>
        <core-animation-prop name="transform" value="translateY(75%)"></core-animation-prop>
      </core-animation-keyframe>
    </core-animation>
```

And I use some Dart code to start the animation on an element:

```
  var animationForm = ($['animOnLoginSuccessForm'] as CoreAnimation);
  animationForm.target = $['form'];
  animationForm.play();
```

I want to define the target of the animation in my HTML so that I only have to call the play method in Dart. How can I do this? I tried everything e.g.:

```
<core-animation target="form" id="animOnLoginSuccessForm" duration="500" fill="forwards" easing="ease-out">
<core-animation target="#form" id="animOnLoginSuccessForm" duration="500" fill="forwards" easing="ease-out">
<core-animation target="{{#form}}" id="animOnLoginSuccessForm" duration="500" fill="forwards" easing="ease-out">
```

But nothing is working. So for me it seems that it's not possible to define the target in HTML, but what do you think? Is it possible and I am just doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

core-animation only supports the following types for `target`:

```
HTMLElement|Node|Array<HTMLElement|Node>
```

So in order to assign the target via an attribute you need to pass at least an HTMLElement.

Try this:

```
<core-animation target="{{ $.form }}" id="animOnLoginSuccessForm" duration="500" fill="forwards" easing="ease-out">
```

Where your `<form>` has set form as id, e.g. `<form id="form" ..`

Comment: Nice, that's what I was looking for. For Dart I had to use {{$['form']}}.